# Finding the cell index to use as an iterator

Tags: tabulator

I am struggling to find the value of the index of each row that when the cell within the row has been edited.

I would like to get the index with the `getIndex()` function. It isn' working. How do I use the row index to iterate through a check that I am performing to check data in another array?

I have tried the following within the tabulator object:

```
let cashReceiptsJournalTable = new Tabulator("#CashReceiptsJournalAnswerArea", {
    data: crjAnswerData,
    layout:"fitColumns",      //fit columns to width of table
    tooltips:true,            //show tool tips on cells
    addRowPos:"top",          //when adding a new row, add it to the top of the table
    history:true,             //allow undo and redo actions on the table
    columnVertAlign:"bottom",
    columns:[                 //define the table columns
        {title:"Doc", field:"document", formatter: function(cell) {
                let cellValue = cell.getValue();

                if (cellValue !== undefined) {
                    if (cellValue === filteredCRJ[index].document) { // trying to use the index to check another array per cell
                        cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#a6ff91";
                    } else {
                        cell.getElement().style.backgroundColor = "#ff8ea4";
                    }
                }
                return cellValue;
            }, width:65, editor:"input", validator: ["string"]},
        {title:"Date", field:"date", width:75, editor: "input", validator: ["integer", "min:1", "max:31"]},
        {title:"Details", field:"details", width:150, editor:"input", validator: ["string"]},
        {title:"Fol", field:"folio", width:60, editor:"input", validator: ["string"]},
        {title:"Analysis of <br>Receipts", field:"analysisOfReceipts", width:120, editor:"input", validator: ["integer", "min:1"]},
        {title:"Bank", field:"bankValue", width:80, editor:"input", validator: ["integer", "min:1"]},
        {title:"Current income", field:"currentIncome", width:140, editor:"input", validator: ["integer", "min:1"]},
        {title:"Sundry", field:"sundry",columns: [
                {title:"Account", field:"account", align: "left", editor:"input", validator: ["string"]},
                {title:"Amount", field:"amount", align:"right", editor:"input", validator: ["integer", "min:1"]}
            ],
        },
    ],
});
```

I haven't been able to get it to work with `formatter` or `cellEdited`.

All I am trying to do is find each index simultaneously as the formatter goes to the edited cell.

I want this to be printed out with a `console.log()`:

```
console.log(cell.getIndex()) // 0 or 3 or 10 depending on where I've just input my information into the table.
```

I want to use the index to find the position in my `filteredCRJ` array in order to gain access to the `document` property value within a nested object within the array.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is because the ***getIndex*** function is on the [Row Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/components#component-row) not the [Cell Component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/components#component-cell)

So you need to be calling:

```
var index = cell.getRow().getIndex();
```

This will only work if you have set a value on the rows data object, by default this is the ***id*** property
{id:1, name:"steve", age:21}

If you are looking for the rows position in the table, you can use the ***getPosition*** function:

```
var position = cell.getRow().getPosition();
```

Comment: Yeah but he asked on cell index not row :)